# Hide loader when Pdf generation finishes with mpdf in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

In Codeigniter, I am generating a pdf using mPDF library. On button click, I show the loader using javascript as below:

```
<button  onclick="showloader()" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Print to PDF</button>
```

This buttons does a postback to a Controller which passes the control to a model function. Inside this model function I have fetch information from databse and generated a PDF from the same

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($a);
$mpdf->Output('Filename.pdf', 'D');
```

Js functions:

```
function loader()
{
    $('#loading').show();
}
function hideloader()
{
    $('#loading').hide();
}
```

How can I call the javascript hideloader() function after this line so that loader gets hidden:

> $mpdf->Output('Filename.pdf', 'D');

Comment: Are you using AJAX to create the PDF?

Comment: No, its not an ajax request. As I mentioned, button hits a post back

Comment: share your showloader() function.

Comment: @Jayesh Added js functions to description